# Please update your system to include revtex4-1.cls

Tags: document-classes, revtex, aastex

I am writing an article, references of which are to be written in AAS style. Now, when I added `{aastex631}` in the document class, it downloaded some class files. However, on compilation it showed the following the error-"**Please update your system to include revtex4-1.cls**" in both TeXworks and WinEdt 10.
Though I'm a newbie in LaTeX, I updated everything I could, from my system to MiKTex updates. On someone's advice, I even copied all the contents of REVTeX.zip in the local tree directory and in the folder containing tex file of the article. But the error is still there.

Comment: revtex4-1  has been declared outdated. It is not installed by miktex anymore. Your class should switch to revtex4-2, or you can get the older version from ctan.

Comment: The files I put into the local directory and document folder were of revtex4-2 only.

Answer (score 4):

revtex4-1 is here https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1, but you will have to unpack the dtx to get the cls.

You could instead try to substitute the class:

```
\makeatletter
\declare@file@substitution{revtex4-1.cls}{revtex4-2.cls}
\makeatother

\documentclass{aastex631}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

In any case write to the maintainer of the aastex631 class and ask them not to use an obsolete class.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But now there's this new error-Command \c@affil already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Comment: my example doesn't error. But it is quite possible that simply replacing the class doesn't work in other places. Write to the maintainer of the class, it is their job to keep this up-to-date.

Comment: Dear @UlrikeFischer, Thank you so very much for this answer. Had it not been for your help, I would have switched to a different journal.